# How to design webpages for Large Vertical Displays?

Tags: html, css, resolution, screen-orientation

I am currently designing an webpage which will be used to display dynamic content on an LED screen in a mall.

I need to make sure that the content I design exactly fits the height and width of the display . The screen size is 42″ and the resolution is 1280 × 720 .

1. How do I make sure that what I design exactly fits the screen? I
   am more worried about making it fit vertically.
2. How can I design content which automatically adapts and fits
   itself to such long vertical screens?
3. Are there any tools that can help me with the design process?

[image: Digital Billboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have many problems, just set your height to 1280px and width to 720px.

A good template would be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #wrapper {
                height:1280px;
                width:720px;
                outline:1px black solid; // useful when designing to see where boundary of screen is.
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Everything goes in here. -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You'll want to find out what browser they are using, then design in that browser. You may well find that it runs Windows XP Embedded with IE 7.

To make it easy to use IE7, I'd recommend setting up a virtual machine running the browser. You can get this from Microsoft here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575&mnui=0, or if you are on OSX or Linux, the frankly amazing https://github.com/xdissent/ievms may be handy.

It would be worth considering carefully what the minimum fontsize is that will be readable. You may also find that if it's a normal screen that has been rotated that the subpixels will be rotated through 90˚, that is, instead of going RGB left to right, they will be arranged vertically. Microsoft's Cleartype will look weird in that case, so if that is turned on then you'll find that smaller text is very blurry. (It works on pixels left and right not up and down, so a rotated screen throws it off considerably).

I'd try to get a copy of the screen, or just run it through your TV and turn your head sideways to approximate it :)

Comment: Thanks Rich. It does run Windows XP with IE7 browser. We will be using it for realtime dynamic content . So cant use just pictures !

Comment: I agree that there will not be any problems or challenges. You can even design it that it will work on any size screen if you use procents instead of pixels for the width, height en positioning of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Questions 1,3: 
Get yourself the "Web Developer" add-on for firefox. In the toolbar, under "Resize" select "Edit Resize Dimensions" and add "Width: 720, Height:1280".
Now you can click on resize, and see exactly how will your design look on the needed screen resolution.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

As for your question number 2:
With jQuery, you can add this code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  var height = $(window).height();
  var width = $(window).width();
  if(width>height) {
    // Landscape
    $("body").addClass("landscape");
  } else {
    // Portrait
    $("body").addClass("portrait");
  }
}
```

It will add the "portrait" or "landscape" class to your pages "body" element. You can now prepend this class to your CSS rules to have conditional design.

Comment: Thanks AndreyKo ! This will help a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You have the benefit of only having to support one device and resolution but you will probably face a few challenges.

### Challenges

- Ensuring that content fits exactly in the space allocated (blank space would look bad on a display like that, as would overflow (of course).
- Dealing with potentially older browsers (as @Rich Bradshaw pointed out) and mediocre CPUs/GPUs.
- The difference in pixel density between a typical desktop monitor and a larger display.
- Color temperature/interpretation and font rendering differences.

### Things which may help

- My first step would be to see if you can have a device given to you as a loaner for testing. I have worked with more than one company who was glad to lend/give a device when it was needed for particular requirements. This is especially important if you are responsible for any part of the visual design (for example, making sure that colors don't bleed, fonts are smooth, etc.)
- If you can't get an actual device, at least see if it is calibrated to a particular color profile, which you can then set on your local machine (in Windows, it's under "Color Management").
- If the content is static, it's pretty easy to put together a fixed dimension layout that will even work on older browsers.
- If the content is dynamic in nature, you could try something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which will attempt to fit disparate content into a dynamic grid. However, it may result in dimensions which are larger than you desire so you will still need to have an approximate idea of the original content. This assumes that you are running a somewhat modern JavaScript engine IE7+)
- Make sure that you fail gracefully. Layout errors are bad enough on websites used from PCs/mobile devices, but errors on a big screen in the middle of a shopping mall really stand out.

I found these guidelines for working with Google TV useful as they deal with design/implementation on larger screens: https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/design_for_tv

Comment: Thanks Tim for the elaborate details . Appreciate it a lot . Cheers